# iOS app crashing with cfrunloop_is_calling_out_to_an_observer_callback_function

Tags: ios, xcode

When running my app I occasionally get this crash that seems not to have anything with my code. What is it and how my I avert it?

> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x000000018fc4c16c
>   mach_msg_trap + 8 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x000000018fc4bfdc mach_msg + 72 2   AudioToolbox
>     0x0000000193c8bcdc ASClient_AudioSessionSetActiveWithFlags + 132 3
>   AudioToolbox                      0x0000000193c6c7f4
>   AudioSessionSetActive_Priv + 360 4   AVFAudio
>     0x00000001aa46bf8c -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:] +
>   84 5   Jam Session                    0x00000001000d41b8 0x1000b0000 +
>   147896 6   Jam Session                    0x00000001000d53fc
>   0x1000b0000 + 152572 7   UIKit
>     0x0000000196ae90ec -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1056 8
>   UIKit                             0x0000000196ba2cdc
>   -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72 9   UIKit                           0x0000000196ba2bb4 -[UINavigationController
>   _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 416 10  UIKit                            0x0000000196ba1efc -[UINavigationController
>   _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 140 11  UIKit                            0x0000000196ba1948 -[UINavigationController
>   _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 856 12  UIKit                            0x0000000196ba14fc -[UINavigationController **viewWillLayoutSubviews]
>   + 64 13  UIKit                            0x0000000196ba1460 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188 14  UIKit                          0x0000000196ae625c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
>   + 1196 15  QuartzCore                     0x0000000193fad2c8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148 16  QuartzCore
>
>     0x0000000193fa1fa4 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) +
>   292 17  QuartzCore                        0x0000000193fa1e64
>   CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32 18 
>   QuartzCore                        0x0000000193f1eb20
>   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252 19  QuartzCore
>     0x0000000193f45f8c CA::Transaction::commit() + 512 20  QuartzCore
>
>     0x0000000193f469ac
>   CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned
>   long, void*) + 120 21  CoreFoundation
>
>     0x0000000190c4a7dc
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 32 22  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000190c4840c
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372 23  CoreFoundation                   0x0000000190b77068 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476 24  UIKit
>     0x0000000196b542ec -[UIApplication _run] + 608 25  UIKit
>     0x0000000196b4f070 UIApplicationMain + 208 26  Jam Session
>     0x00000001000c36d4 0x1000b0000 + 79572 27  libdyld.dylib
>     0x000000018fb585b8 start + 4

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue today after subclassing a `UIView`. To resolve this I did the following:

- Add an Exception Breakpoint for all exceptions
- Enable Zombie Objects

After viewing the thread stack on the left pane, I noticed something related to "key path" and "value".. then I realised that when creating my subclass, I'd created an `IBInspectable` and updated this value in the storyboard. I later removed this and this is what caused the crash, because the class was still trying to set this value at runtime.

So make sure to check your "User Defined Runtime Attributes".

Answer (score 0):

This crash occurs when using `NSNotificationCenter`

You registered a notification observer to an object that has been released and didn't removed the observer. So when it tries to call the selector it crashes.

If you are using a `ViewController` of some kind, you can add

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"Notification" object:nil];
```

to the `viewWillDisappear`

if it is not a ViewController you can use `-(void) dealloc` to unregister the Observer.

In case you to debug further to exactly figure out the point of origin of crash. Put an exception breakpoint in the breakpoints tab and run the app, do casual testing and see if you get the crash.

This should work..

Cheers!

Comment: I do not use any notification in this specific app, but for that used by BWQuincyManager that is anyway removed on the dealloc.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please try that and see if you get the crash..

Comment: Ok, I also enabled the zombie object. Now I need to it to have it crashing again, I am leaving it running and playing.

Comment: Also a mayor problem is that the crashes tend to occur while I am running my app on the AppleWatch and in that case nothing is reported about the iPhone app.

Comment: In fact now it silently crashed again while I run it from my watch and I have no queue about what happened, but for the crash logs.

Comment: @fabrizio did you figure this out?